# Passing a static variable to a Class as argument?

Tags: python, class, static-variables

How can I achieve something like this ?

```
class myClass(static_variable):
    static_var = static_variable

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x + static_var

obj = myClass(static_variable = 3)(x = 5)
#obj.x = 8
```

**[EDIT]**
A better question would be 'How to initialize a class static variable at runtime ?', but python is interpreted so I don't know if this is a better question either.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You could use `type` to dynamically create subclasses of `myClass`, but there may be better solutions given more context.

Comment: Am i the only one that thinks this seems suspect? is this [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?

Comment: If you need a variable that is constant across all classes, and then individual objects add on this constant value separately from each other to create the final attribute, then why not just create the final value directly, keeping this value "constant" as a parameter to the init or even a default value in the init or even just keep it hardcoded?

Comment: Write a function that creates the class and returns it.

Comment: I need to share a static variable among the class' objects, but I first need to compute this variable. I don't know it beforehand.

Comment: Do you want to have *one* kind of ``myClass`` with some value of ``static_var``, or do you want to have *several* kinds of ``myClass`` with separate value of ``static_var`` each?

Comment: @martineau I didn't know that this was even possible

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Just one kind

Comment: It's possible in Python. Just nest the class definition in the function and return it. Each call to it will return a different class.

Comment: Then why don't you define the class *after* you have computed the value of ``static_var``?

Comment: You just want to do an expensive computation once, for figuring out some value that has to be used by all objects, simply put, yes?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Yes

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Will it be in the scope of the class definition ?

Comment: Class definitions are evaluated, they can access values from the scope in which that definition happens (and lexically around it). You can define a ``static_variable``, then literally run the ``class`` code as shown if you leave away the parentheses after ``myClass``.

Comment: The `x + static_var` is the wrong syntax to reference the class' `static_var`.

Comment: @martineau What's wrong with that syntax ? How should it be ?

Comment: It would need to be either `x + myClass.static_var` or `x + self.static_var`.

Comment: @martineau I thought that every class' method had 'access' to the static variables of the Class

Comment: They do, just not the way you're trying to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second line will do the trick. You don't need to subsequently assign it in the constructor.

```
class YourClass:
    static_var = 3*6 . # <--- assigns the static variable to a computed value, 18 in this case
    def __init__(self):
        pass

instance = YourClass()
print(instance.static_var)  # <--- this will print 18
print(YourClass.static_var) # <--- this also prints 18
```

Answer (score 1):

The `class` statement is evaluated at runtime, and it has access to its enclosing scope. This allows class ("static") attributes to be initialised from context or by executing other code.

```
static_variable = 32

class myClass:
    cvar1 = static_variable  # lookup variable from enclosing scope
    cvar2 = random.random()  # call function to initialise attribute

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x + self.cvar1 + self.cvar2
```